# Center an image horizontally

Tags: image, extjs, sencha-touch-2, alignment

this is my GUI:
[image]

I would center the image horizontally....
Can you help me? I can not understand how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

give cls for the component 'yourCls'

```
.yourCls{
  background-image:url('resources/images/startup.png');
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
margin : '30px 0px 0px 0px'
```